# How do i reference the theme path in pages for images?

Tags: images, shortcode, urls

How do i reference images in a page/post without installing the php plugin or typing it out manually like this:

```
domain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/image.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

```
print get_template_directory_uri() . '/image.jpg';
```

In [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) if you have replaced the image.

In a shortcode this would look like this:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Theme URI Shortcode */

add_shortcode('theme_uri', 'wpse_66026_theme_uri_shortcode' );

function wpse_66026_theme_uri_shortcode( $attrs = array (), $content = '' )
{
    $theme_uri = is_child_theme()
        ? get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
        : get_template_directory_uri();

    return trailingslashit( $theme_uri );
}
```

Comment: that looks like a php command, how would i post php into pages? is there another way of doing it like shortcodes?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. See my update.

Comment: does that shortcode already exist? or i have to put it myself? and does it go into the functions.php file?(in the themes folder) thnx

Comment: Put it into a **plugin**. Otherwise the content will be broken after a theme switch. Shortcodes should never go into theme files.